# Как отправить с php client на websoket данные?

Tags: php, websocket

Добрый день. Собственно такая проблема: есть веб сокет на Ratchet, к нему уже подрублен браузер который прекрасно с ним соединяется (в общем проблем с web socket - браузер нет), проблема возникла тогда когда я начал подключать к сокету php скрипт, сам скрипт к сокету подрубается и может от него получать данные, но вот обратно отправлять их на сокет он не может не как. Пробовал через `fwrite` и `stream_socket_sendto`, оба варианта не дали не какого результата.

Код для подключения к сокету:

```
$socket = stream_socket_client('tcp://localhost:8080', $errorNumber, $errorString, 1);
```

stream_set_blocking($socket, 0);

```
    if (!$socket) {
        echo "{$errorString} ({$errorNumber})<br />\n";
    } else {
        $header = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n" .
            "Host: localhost\r\n" .
            "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
            "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
            "Sec-WebSocket-Key: tQXaRIOk4sOhgoq7SBs43g==\r\n" .
            "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n\r\n";

        fwrite($socket, $header);

        while (!feof($socket)) {
            $context = fgets($socket, 1024);

            echo($context);
        }

        fclose($socket);
    }
```

Код самого сокет сервера на ratchet я приводить не буду он стандартный, все как в доке описано.

PS помогите разобраться, а то уже вторые сутки бьюсь все не как не могу понять что я делаю не так, ведь в теории если приведенный мною скрипт может получать данные с сокета, то 100% он должен их и как то отправлять.

Comment: Почему вы не хотите использовать родной пакет https://packagist.org/packages/cboden/ratchet ? Зачем эти велосипеды?

Comment: Проблема в том, что как я понял из чтения доки там для этого нужен ZeroMQ который мне не только не нужен, но и бесполезен будет вместо него уже используем другие вещи. Правда у меня с английским не очень все хорошо, поэтому мог просто проглядеть или не так что то понять.

Comment: За ссылку на то доку буду благодарен.

Comment: Люди помогите, я вообще не знаю что с ним не так, все вроде верно, но не работает, может хоть кто нибудь объяснить, как это делать , наверняка ошибка где то в логике, но где я не знаю, на одном из форумов пишут, что надо держать соединение постоянно открытым, что бы эта штука работала, но оно и так постоянно открыто, и толку от этого нет

Answer (score 2):

Вообщем если у кого возник такая проблема(ответ нашел на 4 странице в гугле в конце), то нужно сделать следующее(данный вариан решения проблемы подходит не только для symfony):

```
<?php
namespace Calc\ApiBundle\Command\Sockets;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class HttpClientCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('server:run')
            ->setDescription('Запускаем сокет.');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $socket = stream_socket_client('tcp://localhost:8080', $errorNumber, $errorString, 1);

        if (!$socket) {
            echo "{$errorString} ({$errorNumber})<br />\n";
        } else {
            $data = "first message";
            $head = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n" .
                "Host: localhost\r\n" .
                "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
                "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
                "Sec-WebSocket-Key: tQXaRIOk4sOhqwe7SBs43g==\r\n" .
                "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n" .
                "Content-Length: ".strlen($data)."\r\n"."\r\n";

            fwrite($socket, $head);
            $headers = fread($socket, 2000);
            echo $headers;
            fwrite($socket, $this->hybi10Encode($data));
            $wsdata = fread($socket, 2000);
            var_dump($this->hybi10Decode($wsdata));
            fclose($socket);

            /*fwrite($socket, $header);

            while (!feof($socket)) {
                $context = fgets($socket, 1024);

                echo($context);
            }

            fclose($socket);*/
        }
    }

    private function hybi10Decode($data)
    {
        $bytes = $data;
        $dataLength = '';
        $mask = '';
        $coded_data = '';
        $decodedData = '';
        $secondByte = sprintf('%08b', ord($bytes[1]));
        $masked = ($secondByte[0] == '1') ? true : false;
        $dataLength = ($masked === true) ? ord($bytes[1]) & 127 : ord($bytes[1]);

        if($masked === true)
        {
            if($dataLength === 126)
            {
                $mask = substr($bytes, 4, 4);
                $coded_data = substr($bytes, 8);
            }
            elseif($dataLength === 127)
            {
                $mask = substr($bytes, 10, 4);
                $coded_data = substr($bytes, 14);
            }
            else
            {
                $mask = substr($bytes, 2, 4);
                $coded_data = substr($bytes, 6);
            }
            for($i = 0; $i < strlen($coded_data); $i++)
            {
                $decodedData .= $coded_data[$i] ^ $mask[$i % 4];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if($dataLength === 126)
            {
                $decodedData = substr($bytes, 4);
            }
            elseif($dataLength === 127)
            {
                $decodedData = substr($bytes, 10);
            }
            else
            {
                $decodedData = substr($bytes, 2);
            }
        }

        return $decodedData;
    }

    private function hybi10Encode($payload, $type = 'text', $masked = true) {
        $frameHead = array();
        $frame = '';
        $payloadLength = strlen($payload);

        switch ($type) {
            case 'text':
                // first byte indicates FIN, Text-Frame (10000001):
                $frameHead[0] = 129;
                break;

            case 'close':
                // first byte indicates FIN, Close Frame(10001000):
                $frameHead[0] = 136;
                break;

            case 'ping':
                // first byte indicates FIN, Ping frame (10001001):
                $frameHead[0] = 137;
                break;

            case 'pong':
                // first byte indicates FIN, Pong frame (10001010):
                $frameHead[0] = 138;
                break;
        }

        // set mask and payload length (using 1, 3 or 9 bytes)
        if ($payloadLength > 65535) {
            $payloadLengthBin = str_split(sprintf('%064b', $payloadLength), 8);
            $frameHead[1] = ($masked === true) ? 255 : 127;
            for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
                $frameHead[$i + 2] = bindec($payloadLengthBin[$i]);
            }

            // most significant bit MUST be 0 (close connection if frame too big)
            if ($frameHead[2] > 127) {
                $this->close(1004);
                return false;
            }
        } elseif ($payloadLength > 125) {
            $payloadLengthBin = str_split(sprintf('%016b', $payloadLength), 8);
            $frameHead[1] = ($masked === true) ? 254 : 126;
            $frameHead[2] = bindec($payloadLengthBin[0]);
            $frameHead[3] = bindec($payloadLengthBin[1]);
        } else {
            $frameHead[1] = ($masked === true) ? $payloadLength + 128 : $payloadLength;
        }

        // convert frame-head to string:
        foreach (array_keys($frameHead) as $i) {
            $frameHead[$i] = chr($frameHead[$i]);
        }

        if ($masked === true) {
            // generate a random mask:
            $mask = array();
            for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
                $mask[$i] = chr(rand(0, 255));
            }

            $frameHead = array_merge($frameHead, $mask);
        }
        $frame = implode('', $frameHead);
        // append payload to frame:
        for ($i = 0; $i < $payloadLength; $i++) {
            $frame .= ($masked === true) ? $payload[$i] ^ $mask[$i % 4] : $payload[$i];
        }

        return $frame;
    }
}
```

Comment: ссылка на оригинал [Оригинал](http://www.codeitive.com/0SmgXkXgqU/websocket-client-in-php.html)

Answer (score 1):

А зачем сокеты? 
Не желаете ли использовать тот же cURL, который намного быстрее и безопаснее сокетов и file_get_contents().

[cURL](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php)

Upd 1:
На недельке увидел просто шикарную библиотеку для сокетов - Socket.io.

Написать серверную часть на Node.js, если это можно сделать на Вашем хостинге и т.п, и подключить прием по сокетам по ключам на Socket.io.

Сегодня буду делать тестовую API.
Пример выложу на гитхабе.

Comment: сокеты нужны как раз для того что бы снизить нагрузку с апихи, сейчас фронт занимается тем, что просто бомбит апиху через Ajax, собственно что бы убрать этот ужас и нужны сокеты.

Comment: При этом сокеты нужны только, что бы связать фронт с апихой, через постоянно соединение, так как то что отдает апиха это данные которые он соберает с разных ресурсов, как раз через cURL, данных этих очень много где то 40 штук, все 40 с разных ресурсов, как следствие не которые из них запрашиваются через прокси, поэтому некотрые могут прйти за секунду другие могут прийти только через 1 минуту, что бы пользователь не сидел и не смотрел на прогруз бар, как раз и нужен сокет который по мере появления данных будет их отдавать на фронт, получая их в свою очередь от разных фоновых процессов.

Comment: Неужели совсем не кто помочь не может. Вообщем что бы было совсем понятно, то я хочу добиться следующего: есть C(клиент) он делает запрос на WS(сокет) сокет передает данные на демона(D) демон ставит полученные данные в очередь (G) дальше процесс который слушает очередь обрабатывает все это дело и обратно WS ну а WS отдает уже C

Comment: Собственно проблема только в том как передать данные на сокет и все

Comment: Все проще сокет поднимается на python/nodejs, потом через redis pub/sub